# Maven archetypes not appearing in m2eclipse Nexus indexer

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse

I'm setting up a new workstation for Java development in Eclipse. On my previous machine, I don't recall having to do anything special to see the standard collection of archetypes under '`New > Other > Maven project > select archetype`' with Nexus Indexer selected. On this machine, the list of archetypes is empty. I can create archetype-based projects from the command line, so it's not a show-stopper, but I just don't understand why the archetypes are missing (and it makes me wonder what else is broken that I haven't noticed yet).

Eclipse 3.5.1, Sun JDK 1.6.0_17, m2Eclipse 0.9.8.200905041414

Comment: I know this question for m2eclipse, however if you would like to use maven command line to generate project using archetype, refer this link [How to generate Maven based Java/J2EE Project using Archetype?](http://www.myjeeva.com/2012/06/how-to-generate-maven-based-java-j2ee-project-using-archetype/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works fine here with the following configuration: Eclipse 3.5.1 20090920-1017, Sun JDK 6u16, m2eclipse 0.9.8.200905041414.

[alt text http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/126/screenshotnewmavenproje.png](http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/126/screenshotnewmavenproje.png)

Are you sure m2eclipse has finished downloading `nexus-maven-repository-index.gz` from the maven central repository? Does this file looks "good"?

BTW, the index is stored in the plugin's metadata location which is `<workspace root>/.metadata/.plugins/org.maven.ide.eclipse/nexus`. As workaround, you could maybe try to copy the index from the machine where everything works to this destination on the "buggy" machine. But this shouldn't be necessary, things should just work.

Comment: Hi Pascal,
Thanks for confirming that. I upgraded to the latest m2eclipse build from Sonatype's `/update-dev` rather than `/update` Eclipse updates URL, and the new version can see the Nexus index fine. I guess it was a problem with the previous build of m2eclipse (or maybe just the fact of doing the update caused the re-indexing!)

Comment: I'd say option 2 as I'm using the build 0.9.8.200905041414 too. But never mind, it's fixed now :)

Comment: @PascalThivent How can you tell if m2eclipse has finished downloading it?  I see no indication anywhere in the Eclipse 3.7.2 UI to indicate this.  This is on Eclipse 3.7.2, Oracle JDK 1.7r4, and m2e 1.0.200.20111228-1245 grabbed from Eclipse Marketplace.

Answer (score 5):

Ian, make sure you update to 0.9.9 (the update-dev).   Open the Maven Repositories view in Eclipse (this is a new view only available in a recent build of m2eclipse).   From here you will be able to right click on a particular remote repository and force a redownload.

Once you do that, open up the console view and select "Maven Console", you should see m2eclipse printing out log messages detailing the index download. If it succeeded or failed.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks tobrien. I have updated to the latest update-dev, and I now have the Nexus index back again.