# Spring security + JPA + Maven

Tags: eclipse, spring, hibernate, maven, jpa

I have a project that I'm using JPA + SS + Maven and I'm having some troubles with Maven.

Dependency:

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.30</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>  
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>  
        <version>4.0</version>  
    </dependency>     

    <!-- for JPA, use hibernate-entitymanager instead of hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- jstl for jsp page -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
     </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When I add the SS dependency, I get an error that is not founding JARs.

SS dependency:

```
<!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Error:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Missing artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-osgi:jar:4.3.5.Final
    - Missing artifact org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:jar:4.7.1
    - Missing artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-envers:jar:4.3.5.Final
    - Missing artifact proxool:proxool:jar:0.8.3
    - Missing artifact org.infinispan:infinispan-commons:jar:6.0.0.Final
    - Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE
    - Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE
    - Missing artifact org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE
    - Missing artifact org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final
    - Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE
- ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer aopalliance:aopalliance:pom:1.0 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/
     maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact aopalliance:aopalliance:pom:1.0 from/to 
     central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled.
etc...
```

Does anybody know how to solve this? Do I will really have to get dependency by dependecy of all those JARs mentioned in the stacktrace or is this any configuration/dependency that I might have forgot?

Many thanks until now!

Comment: There appears to be a connection error when accessing Maven central? Are you behind a proxy? That artifact (aopalliance) is available at Central.

Comment: I don't know, I just configured a new Catalog with this as Catalog File: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml

Is that right?

Comment: I'm new at using Maven, by the way.

Comment: archetype catalogs are not helpful here. Please delete the "~/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/" directory and run `mvn -X compile` to debug what's going on.

Comment: Where do I delete this? I had to configure like that because of this error when trying to create a new maven project:  No archetypes currently available. The archetype list will refresh when the indexes finish updating.

Theres a better way to solve that issue?

Comment: Ok I got it.. I deleted the directory and it worked fine. Is that the real solution? Theres no other configuration to do? I saw something like this (but didnt work): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216794/maven-build-error 
and this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874004/maven-archetypes-not-appearing-in-m2eclipse-nexus-indexer